# How do I relocate the .IntelliJ folder on Windows?

Tags: windows, intellij-idea

When running IntelliJ on Windows in a corporate environment, the .IntelliJ folder can quickly get too big for your profile allowance (especially if you're using Maven) - is there a way to get IntelliJ to point to an alternate location for this folder?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a settings file under `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA\bin\idea.properties` (your location may differ) where you can customize paths to a variety of IntelliJ folders.

Comment: Ah, got it - I need to copy this to my home directory, and then override the properties that start ${user.home}/.IntelliJ

Comment: For me I used Notepad++ in admin mode so that I could update the file where it was.  As I wasn't sure what @RCross meant by home directory.

Comment: Windows user should not overlook good advice in ~line 3: `please make sure you're using forward slashes (e.g. c:/idea/system).` ➝ This also tells us the common guessing points for win users: forward slashes. no doubled (escaped) slashes needed. no trailing slash. lowercase drive letter is good. (not saying anything about uppercase)

Answer (score 5):

This question is [answered in IntelliJ IDEA FAQ](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181):

> Locations of these directories can be modified in `IDEA_HOME\bin\idea.properties` file. You will need to adjust the following parameters:
>
> - idea.config.path
> - idea.system.path
> - idea.plugins.path